# Functions between subsets of a set over which $f$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is it true that for a bijective map $f:X \rightarrow X$, that for any non-empty subset $A$ of $X$ we have that $f:A \rightarrow A$ is also a bijection?

I assume the answer in general is no, in which case does there exist a statement along similar lines to the one written above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ need not map $A$ into $A$: Example: $X=\{1,2\}, f(1)=2,f(2)=1$ and $A=\{1\}$. 
If you know that $f(A)=A$ then $f$ restricted to $A$ is  a bijection on $A$ because it is automatically an injection.

Comment: $x^{3}+1$ does not map $F_p$ into itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a non-empty subset $A$, $f$ doesn't have to restrict to a map $f:A\to A$.

However $f$ always restricts to a map $f:A\to f(A)$, an you can check that this restriction is also a bijection.

Comment: @smoking_huge_doinks this seems to be a totally different question, you should ask another question were you write this specific problem you want to solve.